# Is there an html generator that will allow me to recreate the look from the Microsoft word or Excel

Tags: python, html, css, excel, ms-word

I need to generate nice-looking reports for my boss. I write program in python to generate reports but they are not looking too good, data is fine but I need to make them look better. I try to do it in HTML/CSS but I am bad at the front end so I start looking for an automatic generator but I can't find it good enough. Maybe someone knows a good generator that will allow me to recreate the report look from word. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it is MS Excel look you seek have you tried saving a file in .csv, loading it to Excel and printing it?

Comment: Or if you have sample report file in MS Word you can save it as html and then edit your python code so that it saves output text file on the basis of this muster report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Your HTML Document

*Use one of the following two methods to create your new HTML document.*

**Method 1**

1- Start Microsoft Word.

2- In the New Document task pane, click Blank Web Page under New.

3- On the File menu, click Save.

NOTE: The Save as type box defaults to Web Page (*.htm; *.html).

4- In the File name box, type the file name that you want for your document, and then click Save.

**Method 2**
Start Microsoft Word.

Create a new blank document.

On the File menu, click Save as Web Page.

In the File name box, type the file name that you want for your document, and then click Save.

Add Text and Hyperlinks to Your HTML Document
Open the HTML document that you created earlier in this article. To do this, follow these steps:

On the File menu, click Open.

Browse to the location that you saved your article to, in the "Create Your HTML Document" section of this article.

Select the file and then click Open.

Type the following text into the document:

You can use Microsoft Word to create HTML documents as easily as you can create normal Word documents.

To create a hyperlink, select the words "Microsoft Word" in the text that you typed.

On the Insert menu, click Hyperlink.

In the Insert Hyperlink dialog box, type http://www.microsoft.com/word in the Address box, and then click OK.

Save your changes to the document.

Add an Image to Your HTML Document
Place your insertion point where you want to place an image in your document.

On the Insert menu, point to Picture, and then click ClipArt.

In the Insert ClipArt task pane, click Search.

NOTE: If you click Search without typing anything into the Search Text box, the search result will display all of the currently available images on your system.

In the Results section, select the image that you want to insert into the page.

Save your changes and then close the document.

Open an HTML Document in Word
Do one of the following.

If the New Document task pane is still displayed:

In the New Document task pane, select the document under Open a document. This opens the document directly.

-or-

If the New Document task pane is not displayed:

On the File menu, click Open.

In the Open dialog box, locate the HTML document that you created earlier, and then select it.

Click Open.

REFERENCES
For more information about HTML support in Word 2002, follow these steps:

Open Microsoft Word 2002.

On the Help menu, click Microsoft Word Help.

Click the Answer Wizard tab.

Type HTML in the What would you like to do? box, and then click Search.

Related topics will be displayed. Click any item to display the information.